# How to pass mysql query and connection string and getting results?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms

I have a SQL connection string like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

I have a query like this: `stratdate = 10-03-2001, Enddate = 20-08-2008`

```
string sql =  string.Format(@"SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(visit_Status, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(visit_Status FROM 2))  as Status, COUNT('x') AS Visits
                              FROM visits
                              WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'
                              GROUP BY visit_Status", StartDate.ToString(dateFormat), EndDate.ToString(dateFormat))
```

I don't know how to pass this query to database with connection string and getting the results into datatable. I'm doing WinForms applications with C# and using MySQL as database.

How can I do this? Would anyone have any idea about this? How can I pass this as a command text to MySQL? Would anyone help me with a sample code snippet?

Comment: I hope this article will help..
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabaseAcessWithAdoNet1.aspx

Comment: how can i get the data into datatable not into dataset..would you pls help..

Comment: Thanq renil...for your support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public DataTable GetVisits(System.DateTime startDate, System.DateTime endData)
{
    const string SQL = "SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(visit_Status, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(visit_Status FROM 2))  as Status, COUNT('x') AS Visits FROM(visits)  WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endData GROUP BY visit_Status";
    const string CONNSTR = "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
    var tblVisits = new DataTable("Visits");
    using (var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(CONNSTR)) {
        var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(SQL, conn);
        var da = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var param = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@startDate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Date);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = startDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        param = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@endDate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Date);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = endData;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(tblVisits);
    }

    return tblVisits;
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help. I'm somewhat surprised because it's untested and converted from VB.NET (my default language).